# Remove Git LFS from all branches and histories from a repository

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

We are trying to remove all LFS files from our git repository, so no LFS references are left. We would like this to be done on all branches and all commits back to the start.

We have tried the following command, but it seems to have left some branches with LFS data in them:

```
git lfs migrate export --everything --include .
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check is this help [Remove a file from a older commit without affecting any other commits in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473979/6521116)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. I am wanting to untrack / remove all LFS files from the repo, so it is standard git.